# C++ : meta-data information in source code. To see through AST

Tags: c++, parsing, annotations, metadata, abstract-syntax-tree

After parsing, I want to get a meta-data of the source code's field, or method.

The purpose of this is to collect info of the source code after parsing.

In java, I used annotation. 
After parsing, I find user-defined annotation on class, field, or method.
Under code is example.

```
@BizObject //By this annotation I could understand this class is related with bissness.
public class biz ... {
    @DI //this field needs Dependency Injection.
    public Logger logger;
}
```

By parsing, I want to collect user-specified meta-info of the source.
How user write the meta-data on the source code?? like java annotation.

**I know in C++ there is no direct attribute for this purpose.
I just wondering how to mark meta-data indirectly using other things.**

Comment: There's no such thing in native c++ language.

Comment: If there is nothing, is there idea by using other things?
such as using macro which is just a comment.
In fact, I used this, but couldn't get a comment after parsing. I think scanner skip this.

Comment: Which parser do you use? There are things like `__attribute__` used with some c++ compilers.

Comment: I used eclipse cdt parser. Thanks, I will find __attribute__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self response.

I solved this problem by using **attribute specifier.**
*It is similar to Java's annotation.*

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes
http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/04/18/cxx11-generalized-attributes/
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html

By using attribute specifier and CDT parser, I could get meta data related syntax's node.

**CDT parser support GNU.**